# Setting up JavaFX in IntelliJ - VM options not working at all

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I've been going through Stackoverflow answers for a while now, but none works. Basically I want to run JavaFX in intellij and created the basic JavaFX project. I'm using JDK/JavaFX 13.0.1. I added it under libraries as well. The path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe`

But when I try to set the VM-options, I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\\lib
```

In the VM options I have `--module-path %path% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

for %path%, I have tried everything I've seen on stackoverflow:

```
C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\\lib
\C:\\Program Files\\Java\\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\\lib\
\C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\lib\
C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\lib
same with / instead of \.
```

What the hell is going on, can someone please help me get it running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the path you are referencing in the VM Options contains spaces, it should be surrounded by the double quotes (`"`):

```
-module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-13.0.1\lib"
```